# Я не могу понять, что идет не так

Tags: c#

Я делаю маленькую консольную игрушку, в ней я решил реализовать случайное генерирование карты. Но дело в том, что каждый раз, при возвращении в ту же точку, ее содержимое меняется. Вот пример из "реальной" жизни.

> Вы переехали в новый город. Пошли в магазин, возвращаетесь домой - а там
>   уже водоем. Возвращаетесь обратно в магазин - а там уже парк. Вот так ведет себя
>   мой код.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Adventure
{
    class MainClass
    {
        static int x = 0;
        static int y = 0;
        static Random rnd = new Random();
        static int biome = 0;
        static IDictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int> map = new Dictionary<Tuple<int, int>, int> ();

        public static void Main ()
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("\nSet X");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x);
            Console.WriteLine ("Set Y");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out y);

            Console.WriteLine (x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString() + " | " + biome.ToString());
            MapGen ();
            Main();
    }

    static int MapGen (){
        Tuple<int, int> coords = Tuple.Create (x, y);
        if(map.ContainsKey(coords)){ // If map already has this place generated, then load it, otherwise generate and save.
            map.TryGetValue(coords, out biome);
        }else{
            biome = rnd.Next(0, 6); //0-plains, 1-forest,2-hills,3-taiga,4-desert,5-cave,6-city
            map.Add (coords, biome);
        }
        return biome;
    }
}
```

}

При этом x, y - поля с типом int, в то время как map - поле типа Dictionary. В методе проводится проверка на наличие координат в словаре, если нет - сгенерировать пространство и записать его в словарь, а если же есть-прочитать в словаре, что на них находится и рассказать об этом при помощи `return biome;`.
Спасибо.

Во втором методе, который main, я пробовал вызывать `MapGen()` в разных местах: в начале, в конце, после перемещения на новые координаты, не работает.
UPD: Заменил массив в `Dictionary` на `Tuple`, я догадался, как он работает.

Comment: А разве массивы можно делать ключами словаря?

Comment: Можно, если для массива декларирован IEqualityComparer. Он прописан?

Comment: Замените массив хотя бы на кортеж `Tuple<int,int>`

Comment: Постройте [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): покажите где объявлена `map`, приведите код который можно было бы запустить. Расскажите что вводите в программу, что происходит и что не так. Еще лучше: вместо «загадочного» консольного ввода пропишите значения x и y и последовательные вызовы метода прямо в коде.

Comment: @tym32167 Я пытался использовать Tuple, но я так и не понял, как он работает.

Comment: @defaultlocale В коде сейчас прописаны текущие координаты и система координат работает, как и задумано.

Comment: @Talleyran Нет, не прописан, а что он делает? Извините за глупый вопрос, просто я звлез в неизвестную для меня область языка, до этого я испотзовал Unity

Comment: @JetFly когда вы ищете ключ в словаре, система сравнивает ваш объект Tuple со всеми существующими ключами. Но она не знает как правильно сравнить два кортежа. Нужно явно объяснить что они равны в том случае, когда`x1==x2 && y1==y2`. Для этого объявляется компаратор.

Comment: @Talleyran Спасибо за объяснение, когда будет время, разберусь с IEqualityComparer поподробнее, скорее всего это решит проблему. Единственный вопрос, что мешает системе сравнивать ключ и объект логически, первый член с первым и второй со вторым?

Comment: @JetFly Правильно ли я понимаю, что после изменения на `Tuple` все заработало? Если да, то в чем сейчас вопрос?

Comment: @defaultlocale нет, Tuple не решил мою проблему

Comment: @Talleyran для кортежей компаратор не обязателен, там из коробки используется комбинирование хешкодов от каждой из компонент кортежа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поменяйте:

```
Console.WriteLine (x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString() + " | " + biome.ToString());
MapGen ();
```

на:

```
MapGen ();
Console.WriteLine (x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString() + " | " + biome.ToString());
```

У вас значение `biome` для введенных координат задается в `MapGen`, а выводите вы его до вызова этого метода. Вот и получается, что координаты уже новые, а значение `biome` все еще старое. Отсюда и ощущение что что-то работает не так, хотя на самом деле неправильно только отображается.

В этом легко убедиться в режиме отладки, если поставить точку останова в конце вызова `MapGen` и посмотреть содержимое словаря или просто выполнить программу в пошаговом режиме.

Текущий код с `Tuple` корректно работает со словарем, разве что лично я бы более короткий синтаксис использовал.

Условие в MapGen можно переписать немного короче

```
if(!map.TryGetValue(coords, out biome))
{
    biome = rnd.Next(0, 6);city
    map.Add (coords, biome);
}
```

Работать будет ровно так же.

Вместо Tuple можно использовать структуру

```
struct Coords
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
    public Coords(int x, int y) { X = x; Y = y; }
}
```

Фокус заключается в том, что структуры в C# - это Value Type и базовые реализации GetHashCode() и Equals() структур учитывают содержимое, поэтому они могут применяться в качестве ключей словаря без дополнительных танцев с <strike>бубном</strike> компаратором, если конечно не требуется какое-то особое сравнение, отличное от по-байтового, например строго по значению одного поля, без учета остального содержимого.

С классом такой фокус не пройдет (массив это класс), потому что базовые реализации GetHashCode() и Equals() учитывают только совпадение ссылок и их нужно будет переопределять самостоятельно, либо писать компаратор для словаря.

Comment: Прекрасно. Я просто глупый, вся ошибка была в том, что я рано вызывал MapGen(). Ну, спасибо, хорошего дня ;)

Comment: @JetFly Только не рано, а поздно. Этого можно избежать, если MapGen будет возвращать значение сам. а статическое поле biome убрать совсем.

Comment: Да, извиняюсь, перепутал, поздно. Нет, поле biome убрать не получится, так как MapGen должен возвращать большое количество данных. По крайней мере, в данный момент это невозможно, потому что пока не понятно, где мне может еще пригодиться информация о том, что окружает игрока. Потом я не знаю, как буду выкручиваться, так как данные, получаемые от MapGen будут разных типов

Comment: @JetFly Приведите эти разные данные к общему базовому классу или интерфейсу, и все будет нормально. Вообще по возможности избегайте статических элементов, если в них нет реальной необходимости. Особенно статических полей, т.к. искать кто его поменял, когда и почему гораздо сложнее чем написать пару-тройку лишних строк кода.

Comment: точно, никогда бы не додумался, спасибо за совет